# Don't assume other users are male

Tags: discussion, etiquette

The question [Is it an obligation for everyone to marry?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/12034/is-it-an-obligation-for-everyone-to-marry) had at least one, possibly two answers assuming the question asker was male (Or at least [sexually oriented towards women](http://geekfeminism.wikia.com/wiki/What_about_lesbians%3F))

Please don't do that!